# How to check the output of word2vec

Tags: r

I am using word2vec to train sentences to get most nearest words. I am trying it using word2vec using R language.

Input:

```
"You are my best friend"
```

Output:

```
The model was generated in 'C:/Users/acer/Pictures/INTERNSHIP'!
```

I have used the following code in R:

```
g <- word2vec("mydata.txt","Word.txt")
```

But I have to check output after training the text with word2vec in R. Can anyone please help in trying out the same with R?

Comment: Can you provide us with some of your data in mydata.txt and Word.txt so we can understand what you have done?  You should also include the name of the package you are using in your question.

Comment: mydata.txt includes: "In order", "to perform", "operations inside", "surgeons must", "make an", "incision large", "enough to", "offer adequate", "visibility provide", "hand-held surgical instruments", "intensive care unit". word.txt is the vector representation of each of these bigrams. I cannot open word.txt file.

Comment: What package are you using? `tmcn.word2vec`?

Comment: Yes, I am using tmcn.word2vec package

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find very useful information in the link below. The answer to most of your questions is practically available.
In this source, it is stated how to use and test the word2vec algorithm in R.

Specifically `write.word2vec (model," mymodel.bin ")` to save and retest the model

```
lookslike <-predict (model, c (" jardin "," cafes "), type =" nearest ", top_n = 5)
lookslike
```

http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/100-word2vec-in-R